# Problems with creating an android application

Tags: java, android, sdk

when creating an android application (using gradle and libgdx) i get the following errors, what's the best way to solve them?

[image: Errors]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you add the import for Bundle class? Like this: import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: I recommand you android studio http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Try cleaning your project, sometimes Eclipse can be silly with error messages: Project -> Clean...

Comment: As @AdamCherti said, you should avoid using Eclipse and ADT theses days, Android Studio just got released in its final version and it's much more stable.